# Does break have defined behaviour outside of given/when (aka switch)?

Tags: perl, switch-statement, undefined-behavior

### Update

The apparent problem was only due to a typo in my sample script, as noted by @M42. The `eval` hid the error caused by doing a `break` without `given`. The error message in `$@` is:

```
Can't "break" outside a given block
```

So the case is clear and there is no problem at all. Going to close the question.

### Another Update

Seems a little inconsistent, though; warning in one case but not in the other:

```
$ perl5.12.4 -WE "eval { say 0; say 1 if last; say 2 }; warn if $@; say 3"
0
Can't "break" outside a given block at -e line 1.
        ...caught at -e line 1.
3

$ perl5.12.4 -WE "eval { say 0; say 1 if last; say 2 }; warn if $@; say 3"
0
Exiting eval via last at -e line 1.
Can't "last" outside a loop block at -e line 1.
        ...caught at -e line 1.
3
```

Same output for `perl5.14.1`.

Wondering why those aren't compile-time errors anyway. They are syntax errors after all.

And the message says we can't exit via `last` or `break` when the implementation proves we can - the program simply carries on. Should `eval` really catch such broken code? Just a user wondering ...

### Original post

In a code review, I just saw a copied/pasted `given/when/break` where the `given/when` was deleted and the `break` was left over. The code compiles and runs without warnings. Which led me to the question:

Does `break` have defined behaviour outside of `given/when` ?

I couldn't find anything authoritative in [`perlsyn`](http://p3rl.org/perlsyn). And I can't see what would be the `break`-rationale from the output of the following program:

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub bla {
    my @args = @_;
    eval {
        for ( @args ) {
            say;
            if ( $_ eq 'blub' ) {
                say '==> break';
                break;
            }
            say 'nach if';
        }
        say 'nach for';
    };
    say 'eval Ende';
    say 'sub Ende';
}

bla qw/ eins zwei blub drei /;

say for '-' x 40;

eval {
    say 'im eval';
    say '==> break';
    break:
    say 'immer noch im eval';
};
say 'nach dem eval';
```

Identical output with 5.10.1, 5.12.4 and 5.14.1. Note in the first example all of `eval/for/if` are skipped, whereas in the second example `eval` continues.

```
eins
nach if
zwei
nach if
blub
==> break
eval Ende
sub Ende
----------------------------------------
im eval
==> break
immer noch im eval
nach dem eval
```

So is it undefined behaviour? Or do you have any relevant doc pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a semicolon instead of a colon after the break instruction

```
break;
```

With a colon it is considered as a label.

Comment: Thanks, what a stupid mistake of mine. If you then read `$@` after the eval, you get: `Can't "break" outside a given block`. I'm going to update and close this question.

Comment: Hmm, I can't delete my own question because it has answers. So it'll stay here. Or do you happen to know how you could delete/close a question other than voting to close?

Comment: @Lumi: Sorry, I don't know how to do. But I think you could ask a moderator.

Comment: @Axeman:Thanks for correction.